# Powershell converts consecutive "+" into a space

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.4

I'm kind of at a loss. On one of my computers, whenever I am using Powershell 7.4.1, it will not recognize consecutive "+"s when typing. If I type (2) "+" in a row, the first one is converted to a space. Three or more "+"s and the "+" that was a space becomes a "+" again.

Attached is a screenshot of Notepad++ as you can see the first "+" is missing.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI6HH.png)

Troubleshootng steps performed:

1. Checked Windows Powershell and the issue does not exist.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled PowerShell 7.4.1
3. Duplicated the setup that's on my other machines that do not have this issue.
4. Disabled all forms of Windows autocompletion/autocorrection
5. Googled the issue
6. Bing'ed the issue
7. Yahoo'ed the issue

None of the above resolved the issue or could help explain the issue.

Comment: Does the issue go away if you don't load your profile script(s)? `pwsh -noprofile`

Comment: It still persists. I deleted my profile and I still get the issue.

Comment: Try using a backtick before the plus sign.  Looks like the plus sign is being interpreted as a plus.

Comment: @AntonioTurner - did you try specifically starting PowerShell with ```pwsh -NoProfile``` per MathiasRJessen's suggestion? PowerShell can load multiple profiles from different locations so the most reliable way to disable them all is with ```-NoProfile```...

Comment: @mklement0 It seems as if the issue is with account. If I open PowerShell 7.4.1 as admin the issue does not exisit. I also discovered if I type "..." they become "?." I'm wondering if it is some vscode, visual studio or WSL that is causing the problem. I can uninstall both IDEs, but not WSL. I'll report back.

Also when I removed oh-my-posh and deleted my profile I had the default prompt, but still the issue.

Comment: @mclayton Yes I did. However, I did just open up cmd and ran the prescribed command and the issue does not exist using that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank everyone for their help. After following the suggested troubleshooting, I realized opening PowerShell 7 from the Start Menu had no issues, but running it from Windows Terminal generated the 'gremlins'.

I backed up my settings.json and started fresh and the issue is gone. This is where I thought the story ended. Further investigation revealed this was a self-imposed issue with a custom PSReadline script I was developing. The script was doing some autocorrect, but my captures were way off.  “..” was supposed to turn into “. ” instead I was reading “+” I also thought when I uninstalled and flushed everything the PSReadline settings were reset.

Things that helped me further deep dive, this was a dev VM that I take constant snapshots, so I was able to go back and walk through the issue since it’s incarnation.